# Typescript can't be compiled in vs code: error TS5007

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I just installed vs code v1 (the latest version) and typescript v1.8.10 (latest version).
I followed the exact instruction from vs code [website](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript) but can't get vs code to build the simplest typescript file though I can manually build it by running tsc command in git bash. The output from the vs code is:

```
error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: '.'.
error TS5023: Unknown option 'p'
Use the '--help' flag to see options.
```

This is the my helloworld.ts file which really can't be simpler:

```
class Greet {
    private _message : string;
    constructor(message : string) {
        this._message = message;
    }
    Say = () => console.log(this._message);
}

var g = new Greet('hello typescript!');
g.Say();
```

This is my tasks.json file:

```
{
    // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

and tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe it can help as mentioned at [(VS Code, error, TS5023) Unknown compiler option 'p'](http://blog.vector3d.xyz/blog/programming/vscode/2015/08/31/vscode-error-ts5023.html)

Open your environment settings and remove the old Typescript from your system PATH variable. Mine was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\`.

1. Hold Windows Button and hit the PauseBreak key
2. Advanced System Settings
3. Environment Variables
4. In the "System" panel (the bottom in Windows 10) select the `Path` variable and click `Edit`
5. Find and highlight an old version like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\` in the text, delete it. Press "OK" three times.
6. Restart VS Code

Comment: thanks; that fixed the problem. Can't believe people from MS didn't think about when they were writing the typescript document for vs code...

Comment: As Fabio Turati commented below, the solution is adding a new Variable pointing to your TypeScript version. e.g: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\.  I simply copied his suggestion here to make it more visible.

Comment: By now you can remove Visual Studio 2013 and use a newer version.

Answer (score 8):

I got this error in vs code. *Box* *[Windows 08, VS Code]*

```
 error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: '.'.
   error TS5023: Unknown option 'p'
   Use the '--help' flag to see options.
```

**Solution**

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`
2. If you have both 1.0 and 1.8 version then rename or delete `1.0`. If you don't have `1.8` version then install new typescript version from [official download page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links). *I installed Visual Studio 2013*

Then it worked.

**Note:** - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36800871/5090579) suggests to do same thing. I am writing this answer to explicitly show all the steps. Also, I think community discourages, while answering, to just link the article, since link can go dead.

Comment: As a general tip, do not refer to "the above answer". It's above yours *now*, because it has a higher score, but that could change. And others might post yet more answers, and then it could be difficult to understand which one you mean. The solution is to add a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

> I resolve this problem by simply delete all  older version of
>   typescript. In my case i move to installed location of typescript
>    like

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript** 
, this is the location where all typescript version installed.
after deleting file and reopen visual studio code and it works fine!